# Getting variables and assigning them in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to get 10 variables from an HTML form. All variables in HTML are in format (v1, v2.....v10)

I can do it like following without a problem

```
var1=request.GET.get("v1")
var2=rquest.GET.get("v2")
...
```

This is very repetitive. I am trying to get them in a list with a loop.

```
var=[]
  for i in range(10):
    placehold="var"+str(i)
    var[i]=request.GET.get(placehold)
```

This is not working. How can I get those 10 variables into a list using for loops?

In addition, even if I get all values in a manual way I can't put them in a list in a for loop

```
newlist=[]
  for i in range(10):
    combined="var"+str(i)
    newlist.append(combined)
```

is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may want to consider a dictionary for this use case. (At least for the first code block).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is referencing an empty list

```
var[i]=request.GET.get(placehold)
```

Try changing it to

```
newlist = []

for i in range(10):
    placehold="var"+str(i)
    item = "v" + str(i)
    placehold=request.GET.get(item)
    newlist.append(placehold)
```

Comment: I deleted the first placehold assignment and it worked. Thank you very much